# How do I replace a hard-coded string with a variable in elisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm trying write an elisp function with a string that is set based on the filetype of the current buffer (but isn't just the filetype). For example, how would I replace this:

```
(defun run ()
  (interactive)
   (async-shell-command (concat "./" (file-name-base buffer-file-name)))
   )
```

with this:

```
(defun run ()
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command (concat cmd (file-name-base buffer-file-name)))
  )
```

where cmd = "./"

I've tried to use defvar, but I get an error whenever I try to use a string, but this:

```
(defvar flowers)
  (set 'flowers '(rose)
```

makes flycheck give me the error, "global/dynamic var `flowers' lacks a prefix" (and it doesn't work in my function).

Comment: This is one of the least-clear questions I've seen. It seems as if you're recreating your code from memory rather than copying from Emacs. You've replaced the original code entirely. Your example variable exists nowhere in your code, so it's impossible to know what you're attempting to do. If you want assistance, please copy and paste code that you have actually tried using, and make your examples relevant.

Answer (score 2):

So I can only presume you didn't actually try running your own code? You're trying to make a modified version of something which doesn't work in the first place.

Just replace the string with the variable name, but *not* (in either case) in parentheses, because `("foo")` and `(someVariable)` are both attempts to *call a function*.

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "foo")
  )

(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command someVariable)
  )
```

Comment: I thought I included the parentheses when I tested my function... I looked back at it and it turns out I didn't.